# Database first approach in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am trying to create a new ASP.NET Core application with database first approach. My database tables are already built. I have created my models manually, I do not want to reverse engineer to create model from the database.

When I am browsing my page, I got following error.

In ASP.NET MVC 5, there used to be a line `Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);` to keep in the ApplicationDbContext that stops the app from matching the database with the Model schema, is there any equivalent way in ASP.NET Core?

[image]

Any expert opinion?

Comment: How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: Please use the following link: https://ef.readthedocs.io/en/staging/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html#